# Is there a way to avoid joining an online game?

Tags: need-for-speed-2015

When loading the game, I usually hit 'All drive' and then I have to wait about 2-3 minutes for the game to load as it goes online and tries to find a game for me to join.

I find this aspect of the game quite frustrating. Is there some way to play the game without having to search for and join an online session?

Or am I stuck having to fire up the game, then go find something else to do for 5 minutes whilst it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFS 2015 is intended to be an always-online game.

You can play solo by going to the *Game Settings* and selecting *Play Solo*. However, you can only do that when you have already started an *All Drive* (connected) game, and you will be greeted by another loading screen. It's definitely not going to reduce the time required to get to your car.

You still need to be online. It's just not multiplayer anymore.

There's a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfkq03JwfPU) showing the process (not mine).

PS: I realise this is a very late answer but Google directed me here so someone else may be interested.